# ServiceManager Implementation in UnitTests Visual Studio

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, soa

I'm trying to write a unit tests and I noticed there's a manager service that all the controllers are using, but I cannot initialize it.  Any advice on how I can utilize it?

An explanation about how it's being initialized and passed to the controllers will also be nice (even a link, as I'm not sure where to start looking)

[image]

Comment: Is `MyManager` wrap `ServiceManager` class? how many methods of `MyManager` are being in use in `TaskController`? are you use and mocking framework? if so which one?

Comment: There will likely be an IoC container which is looking after the lifecycle of the MyManager instance which gets injected in. That said it does look strange. Normally the injected type would be an interface rather than a class. See if you are referencing a container such as Unity or Castle Windsor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a typical pattern to Inject a class into your controller.  No idea what MyManager is beyond  its a class that does or contains .  Unless it is an abstract class you should be able to do something like

```
var MyVar = new MyManager();
```

If you have access to this code in VS, position your cursor on MyManager and hit F12 to see the definition.

Comment: The thing is MyManager is a class that I didn't see how it gets initialized, or how it's being passed to the controller.  I even looked in glolbal.asax.cs

The only constructor that class has, takes 15 different interfaces as params.

Comment: @Devaffair as John has said, the controllers are almost certainly being builtup recursively by an IoC container and dependencies are being injected as needed. For testing controllers directly, you will need to provide Real or Fake implementations of all dependencies required. Generally, it is better to couple to an Interface (i.e. `IManager`) than a concrete class, as this will allow easier Mocking of the dependencies, e.g. with Moq